# How do I set the distance between the language with the menu icon down in select?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

My code like this :

```
    <v-select
      v-model="e1"
      :items="states"
      menu-props="auto"
      label="Select"
      hide-details
      prepend-icon="language"
      single-line
      class="custom"
    ></v-select>
```

Demo and full code like this : https://codepen.io/trendingnews/pen/NWPjbvX

If I choose Indonesia, the distance between Indonesian writing and the icon down menu is very fitting

But if I choose English, the distance between English and the menu down icon is too far

[image]

How do i make it dynamic?

I had try to set it by css, but i'm still failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `.v-select__selection--comma` `width: 100%` and `text-align: right` and all languages will have the same distance from the dropdown icon, or use `terxt-align: center` if you want the text to be right between the icons

```
.v-select__selection--comma {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      e1: 'Indonesia',
      states: [
        'Indonesia', 'English',
      ],
    }
  },
})
Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

```css
.custom .v-input__slot::before,
.custom .v-input__slot::after {
  border: none!important
}

.v-select__selection--comma {
  margin: 7px 4px 7px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.15/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.1.15/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="10">
          <v-subheader>Logo</v-subheader>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="2" align="right">
          <div style="width:139px;">
            <v-select v-model="e1" :items="states" menu-props="auto" label="Select" hide-details prepend-icon="language" single-line class="custom"></v-select>
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But when choosing English it makes english writing with the language icon has too much distance. Can it also make the language icon shift right too?

Comment: you can use `width: min-content` for that, see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/ramsegev/pen/zYxwZWj)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your css file , hope it will help you . because of **display flex property** it wasn't center . Tested it through your codepen, Hope it will work. Let me know if not works.

```
.v-select__selections {
    align-items: center;
    display: initial;
    flex: 1 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: heres the codepen, could you please check that, its working here. and totally center align. 
https://codepen.io/salmanaabir/pen/BayRYGJ